# How to identify the correct Angular signal with effect()?

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-signals

The signals in Angular are pretty nice. However I'm struggling with handle multiple signals. In a very simplified example is a service `ExternalController` that defines two signals `controller1` and `controller2`.

Now I want to trigger a method if a signal value changes.

```
service ExternalController {
    public controller1 = signal(null);
    public controller2 = signal(null);

    constructor() {
        effect(() => {
            if (controller1) do something
            if (controller2) do something else
        })
    }
}
```

The problem is that `effect()` fires whenever a signal has changed. But how can I find out **which** signal has fired?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Effect callbacks  are run in a reactive context. It means it's able to know on which signal it depens. If you only call a single signal in effect, this effect will only be invoked when the said signal is updated.

Effect does not run for signal updates that are invoked outside of it.

In you case you could have 2 effects :

```
effect(() => {
   if (controller1()) {
     ...
   }
})

effect(() => {
   if (controller2()) {
     ...
   }
})
```